# Keras throws `'Tensor' object has no attribute '_keras_shape'` when splitting a layer output

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, word-embedding, sentence-similarity

I have sentence embedding output X of a sentence pair of dimension `2*1*300`. I want to split this output into two vectors of shape `1*300` to calculate its absolute difference and product.

```
x = MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(1,MAX_SEQUENCE_LENGTH),strides=(1,1))(x)
x_A = Reshape((1,EMBEDDING_DIM))(x[:,0])
x_B = Reshape((1,EMBEDDING_DIM))(x[:,1])

diff = keras.layers.Subtract()([x_A, x_B])
prod = keras.layers.Multiply()([x_A, x_B])


nn = keras.layers.Concatenate()([diff, prod])
```

Currently, when I do `x[:,0]` it throws an error saying `AttributeError: 'Tensor' object has no attribute '_keras_shape'`. I assume the result of splitting of tensor object is a tensor object that doesn't have `_keras_shape`.

Can someone help me solve this? Thanks.

Comment: Hi, I am trying to run your code by completing it my self but unable to get the error you are getting...can you post complete code ?

Comment: I got the error when compile the model. The below answer fixed it. Thank :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Keras adds some info to tensors when they're processed in layers. Since you're splitting the tensor outside layers, it loses that info.

The solution involves returning the split tensors from Lambda layers:

```
x_A = Lambda(lambda x: x[:,0], output_shape=notNecessaryWithTensorflow)(x)
x_B = Lambda(lambda x: x[:,1], output_shape=notNecessaryWithTensorflow)(x)
x_A = Reshape((1,EMBEDDING_DIM))(x_A)
x_B = Reshape((1,EMBEDDING_DIM))(x_B)
```